# custom error page not being used

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm having trouble getting my custom error page to work. I have followed the instructions on http://docs.ghost.org/themes/ and added an `error.hbs` template into the root of my theme. The code inside this template is really simple:

```
{{!< default}}
<section class="error">
    <h1>{{code}}</h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</section>
```

Each time I try to test it by going to a non existent page, the blog shows the default ghost error page every time.

Have I missed anything crucial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ghost 0.4.2 I'm sorry this is a bug and would be fixed in 0.5 release

see the bug issue at github
https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/2513

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted Ghost? Whenever you add or remove a theme file you need to restart the application for it to become aware of the changes to your file structure. Edits to files are detected automatically, but new or removed files need this extra step.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, and I have restarted Ghost

Comment: I'm seeing this on local ghost instances, but when I published to the hosted instance, the custom error page is showing up.

Comment: I did restart it but I don't have a live server to test it on. It's only on my local machine at the moment.